# AVR proteus delay not working

Tags: c, avr, atmega16

I have used an AVR ATMEGA16 block in Proteus and programmed it this way. 
Some other simple codes work fine. However I do not understand what is wrong with the delay function. The LED is always off. What is wrong?

My Proteus connection is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGNYc.png

```
/*****************************************************
This program was produced by the
CodeWizardAVR V2.05.3 Standard
Automatic Program Generator
© Copyright 1998-2011 Pavel Haiduc, HP InfoTech s.r.l.
http://www.hpinfotech.com

Project : 
Version : 
Date    : 3/8/2015
Author  : 
Company : 
Comments: 


Chip type               : ATmega16
Program type            : Application
AVR Core Clock frequency: 16.000000 MHz
Memory model            : Small
External RAM size       : 0
Data Stack size         : 256
*****************************************************/

#include <mega16.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

// Declare your global variables here

void main(void)
{
// Declare your local variables here

// Input/Output Ports initialization
// Port A initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T 
PORTA=0x00;
DDRA=0x00;

// Port B initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T 
PORTB=0x00;
DDRB=0x00;

// Port C initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In 
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T 
PORTC=0x00;
DDRC=0x00;

// Port D initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=Out 
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=1 
PORTD=0x01;
DDRD=0x01;

// Timer/Counter 0 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer 0 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC0 output: Disconnected
TCCR0=0x00;
TCNT0=0x00;
OCR0=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 1 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer1 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFFFF
// OC1A output: Discon.
// OC1B output: Discon.
// Noise Canceler: Off
// Input Capture on Falling Edge
// Timer1 Overflow Interrupt: Off
// Input Capture Interrupt: Off
// Compare A Match Interrupt: Off
// Compare B Match Interrupt: Off
TCCR1A=0x00;
TCCR1B=0x00;
TCNT1H=0x00;
TCNT1L=0x00;
ICR1H=0x00;
ICR1L=0x00;
OCR1AH=0x00;
OCR1AL=0x00;
OCR1BH=0x00;
OCR1BL=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 2 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer2 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC2 output: Disconnected
ASSR=0x00;
TCCR2=0x00;
TCNT2=0x00;
OCR2=0x00;

// External Interrupt(s) initialization
// INT0: Off
// INT1: Off
// INT2: Off
MCUCR=0x00;
MCUCSR=0x00;

// Timer(s)/Counter(s) Interrupt(s) initialization
TIMSK=0x00;

// USART initialization
// USART disabled
UCSRB=0x00;

// Analog Comparator initialization
// Analog Comparator: Off
// Analog Comparator Input Capture by Timer/Counter 1: Off
ACSR=0x80;
SFIOR=0x00;

// ADC initialization
// ADC disabled
ADCSRA=0x00;

// SPI initialization
// SPI disabled
SPCR=0x00;

// TWI initialization
// TWI disabled
TWCR=0x00;

while (1)
{
      PORTD.0=1;
      _delay_ms(500);
      PORTD.0=0;
      _delay_ms(500);
}


}// end of program
```

Comment: "*The LED is always off.*" Perhaps it's broken?

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27081/using-avr-gcc-delay-ms-causes-chip-to-freeze

Comment: Did you define `F_CPU`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

It is because of your Atmega Clock.
You set your clock on your code at 16 MHz. But proteus initial properties set it at 1 MHz.
So Set your clock of your code at 1 MHz.

Notes:

1.As i know Atmega initial clock can not be more than 8 MHz.

2.If you want to use 16 MHz clock, you should use an external clock.

3.If your clock is not 1 MHz (on your code), you should change proteus Atmega clock by this way:
On Proteus:
Right click on the Atmega -> Edit Properties -> CKSEL FUSES (Set it's clock)

[Proteus Atmega Clock Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xoay.png)